# How to convert $1<\frac{x}{\sin x}<\frac{1}{\cos x}$ to $1>\frac{\sin x}{x}> \cos x$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

> How to convert $1<\frac{x}{\sin x}<\frac{1}{\cos x}$ to $1>\frac{\sin x}{x}> \cos x$?

This is done in the process of deriving the sine function. This is maybe a simple but important bug in my understanding that needs to be fixed. Thanks in advance

Comment: If $0 < a < b$, then $0 < \frac{1}{b} < \frac{1}{a}$, for $$\frac{1}{a} - \frac{1}{b} = \frac{b-a}{ab},$$ and by assumption $b-a > 0$ and $ab > 0$.

Comment: This means $1<\frac{x}{sinx}$ and $\frac{x}{sinx}<\frac{1}{cosx}$. Now multiplication and division (assuming x, $sinx$ and $cosx$ are all positive) easily makes the first inequality equivalent to $\frac{sinx}{x}<1$, which is your first requirement. Similarly for the second inequality.

Comment: @Paul But you don't need all of $x, \sin x, \cos x$ to be positive (they almost certainly aren't in the context of differentiation where $x$ likely approaches $0$ from either side).  It's enough for $\cos x$ and $\sin x/x$ to be positive.